# How do bounds adjust with derived distributions(AKA transformed RV)?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

So I have this function $f(x)=2x^{-2}, x>2$ and $0$ otherwise.

Calculate pdf of $Y=\sqrt X$
The solution says that the lower bound becomes $\sqrt 2$, is this because $Y=\sqrt X$? How do the bounds of Y adjust based on X if we're transforming one function to another and why?

Comment: Note that because $x\mapsto\sqrt x$ is an increasing function, $x>2$ if and only if $\sqrt x>\sqrt2$ (here we are considering $x\mapsto\sqrt x$ as the positive square root).

Comment: Aw I see, I didn't think about whether the function was increasing or decreasing